# Corona (Lua) os.time and system.preferences doesn't work installing in android

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I have a Lua code and it works fine on my simulator on Mac, but when i install the apk on Android the system.preference code and the os.time() function doesn't work, anyone knows what is happen?
Then random result is always the same on android smartphone, but in simulator it always change, and the language is always en in my smartphone, but it is with language pt.

Bellow follows my calls of this functions and my config.lua, anyone can help me?
Thanks!

Call 1:
    function passaroVoar( event )
    -- random x e y

```
math.randomseed( ( os.time() + progresso) * 2 );
local x = math.random(1,screenW);

if ( x < 45 )
then
    x = 45;
elseif (x > screenW - 45) then
    x = screenW - 45;
end

math.randomseed( os.time() * 3 );
local y = math.random(1,screenH);

if ( y < 45 )
then
    y = 45;
elseif (y > screenH - 45) then
    y = screenH - 45; 
end
if ( x > screenW - 305 and y < 30)
then
    passaroVoar ( event )
else
    birdSprite.x = x;
    birdSprite.y = y;
end
end
```

Call of system.getPreference:

```
if (system.getPreference("ui", "language") == "pt")
then
    textoTempo = textoTempo;
else
    textoTempo = "Time:";
end
```

and my config.lua

```
local aspectRatio = display.pixelHeight / display.pixelWidth

application = {
  content = {
     width = aspectRatio > 1.5 and 320 or math.ceil( 480 / aspectRatio ),
     height = aspectRatio < 1.5 and 480 or math.ceil( 320 * aspectRatio ),
     scale = "letterBox",
     fps = 30,

  imageSuffix = {
     ["@2x"] = 1.5,
     ["@4x"] = 3.0,
  },
 },
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

system.getPreference("ui", "language") function may return a full language name on Android device. For example while it returns "en" in simulator it may return "English" on Android device.